# How to Create Manifest for Existing Objects and Strip Identifiers?

Tags: kubernetes

Goal: Create a generic manifest for an existing deployment and strip the cluster distinct details.  Deploy this manifest on a different cluster.

Progress:

`kubectl get deployment <DEPLOYMENT_NAME> -n <NAMESPACE> -o yaml`

Generates a deployment file but it has all sorts of info that is distinct to this cluster / instantiation and must be stripped.  For example:

`lastTransitionTime: 2019-03-20T23:38:42Z`

`lastUpdateTime: 2019-03-20T23:39:13Z`

`uid: 53444c69-acac-11e8-b870-0af323746f0a`

`resourceVersion: "97102711"`

`creationTimestamp: 2018-08-30T23:27:56Z`

... just to name a few.

Is there an option to remove these fields in return or an easy way to only pull the minimum definitions to replicate the object in another cluster?

Comment: While it won't get you all the way there, are you aware of `kubectl get --export=true deployment etcetc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Matthew L Daniel `kubectl get deployment <DEPLOYMENT_NAME> -n <NAMESPACE> -o yaml --export=true` will do the work.

You can also find useful kubectl tricks [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) and [here](https://github.com/dennyzhang/cheatsheet-kubernetes-A4). Additionality full kubectl reference can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands).

Comment: When getting a service, this stripped: creationTimestamp, namespace, resourceVersion, uid, clusterIP.  I guess I disagree with namespace being stripped but I can easily re-add.  Who defines resourceVersion?

Comment: I believe API server defines resourceVersion, more info [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#concurrency-control-and-consistency)